# How can i mention current date in django rest framework filter field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework and i am using django filters for query parameters like this

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering

`stime = django_filters.DateFilter(name='start_time', lookup_type='lte')`

for that i need to pass current time from javascript in query paraemters.

is there any way that if i pass stime as true in query parameters then the actual query to execute on server becomes

`report__stime__lt= datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateRangeFilter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/blob/bd3175677a257f6e6d115a64b6c53b50da251f0f/django_filters/filters.py#L153) in django_filters has already a similar functionality. It has predefined filters for today, this month etc. You can easily extend it to come up with a now filter.